# CacheKeyFactory and Manifest file in ExoPlayer2

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

morning guys,
I created a custom `CacheKeyFactory` and implemented `buildCacheKey`, however, when I tried to print out `dataSpec.uri.toString()` inside the `buildCacheKey`, I saw manifest uri is also being printed out inside `buildCacheKey`.

So my question is that,

1. is the video manifest file also being transformed inside the `buildCacheKey`? (since my logic only cover the transform for actual audio files)
2. if the manifest file is also being transformed, would that cause my cache loading issue or how would the exoPlayer to detect if this is the manifest file after transformation?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been awhile and no one answers this question. for my first question, the answer is yes, the video manifest file will also being transformed, so you might need to handle it differently in the buildCacheKey method.

Second question, as I explained in the first question, it could or could not affect your cache loading issue depends on your usage, but mostly, if you handled it differently, then should be fine.